# Grouping by object - Java streams

Tags: java, collections, java-8, java-stream

I have a list of data like the one given below:

```
List<Data> data = new ArrayList<Data>();
data.add(new Data("d1", "option1"));
data.add(new Data("d2", "option1"));
data.add(new Data("d1", "option2"));
data.add(new Data("d3", "option1"));
data.add(new Data("d3", "option2"));
data.add(new Data("d3", "option3"));
```

The structure looks like this:

```
class Data {
    private String name;
    private String option;
    private List<String> options = new ArrayList<>();
    public Data(String name, String option) {
        this.name = name;
        this.option = option;
    }

    public void addOption(String option) {
        options.add(option);
    }
}
```

How to group the items to a new array based on the name with its options,

```
[
"d1": {
    "name": "d1",
    "options": ["option1", "option2"]
},
"d2": {
    "name": "d2",
    "options": ["option1"]
},
"d3": {
    "name": "d3",
    "options": ["option1", "option2", "option3"]
}
]
```

Comment: To clarify: Do you want the output as a JSON-String? Or a way to get all `option` fields in the `options` field of a new instance of `Data`? For the latter I would already recommend  to change something because it's weird to have both a list of options and a single String option in your class if they both basically mean the same.

Comment: You can't instantiate `List`; it's an interface. Why does `Data` have both a single `option` and a list of `options`? You never call `addOption`. Also, you can't group them to an array. Do you mean a `Map`?

Comment: No JSON, just for brevity I have given the object structure like that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a `Collectors.toMap` collector:

```
Map<String,Data>
    grouped = data.stream()
                  .collect(Collectors.toMap(Data::getName,
                                            d -> new Data(d.getName(),d.getOption()),
                                            (d1,d2) -> {d1.addOptions(d2.getOptions()); return d1;});
```

This will require changing the `Data` constructor to add the passed option to the options `List` as well as adding an `addOptions` method that receives a list of options and adds all of them to the options `List` of the current instance.

Comment: This approach looks convenient for me, I get collection of type "Data" as values from the result map, than of type List<String>.

Answer (score 3):

Try this out,

```
final Map<String, List<String>> optionsByName = dataList.stream().collect(
        Collectors.groupingBy(Data::getName, Collectors.mapping(Data::getOption, Collectors.toList())));
```

I would suggest you to use this `map` as a source to create the DTO you need, without cluttering your code to get the exact result you want.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a simple grouping collector on the stream:

```
Map<String, List<String>> optionMap = data.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Data::getName, 
                     Collectors.mapping(Data::getOption, Collectors.toList())));
```

When tested with your test list, the above produces this output:

```
{d1=[option1, option2], d2=[option1], d3=[option1, option2, option3]}
```

The above seems like a better, type-safe alternative to your desired map. Additionally, it avoids unnecessary duplication.

Your final map can nonetheless be computed based on the above:

```
Map<String, Map<String, Object>> m = new HashMap<>();
optionMap.entrySet().forEach(entry -> {
    Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put("name", entry.getKey());
    map.put("options", entry.getValue());

    m.put(entry.getKey(), map);
});
```

The `m` map above looks like:

```
{d1={name=d1, options=[option1, option2]}, 
 d2={name=d2, options=[option1]}, 
 d3={name=d3, options=[option1, option2, option3]}}
```

This is what you need, but it seems that it contains duplicated data, and it's less type-safe than the simple map in the previous result.